# I need to access a derived class member through the base class static variable

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I need to access the derived class member variable through Base class variable.

```
Class A{

};

Class B:public A {
  int data;  
};
```

now I need to do something like this

```
A *pb = new B()
pb->data = 10;
```

but the problem is I cannot access the Derived member class wihtout it.

and Yeah I know how to make it work with virtual functions.

Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: You cannot. Because your compiler does not know what `pb` is. it could be of type `A`. However, you an use `dynamic_cast`, which returns a `B` pointer or `NULL` if that is not possible.

```
A *pa = new B();
B *pb = dynamic_cast<B*>(pa);
if (pb) {
    pb->data = 10;
}
else {
    ...
}
```

Anyhow, if you need to do that it probably means that you should revise your design as upcasting is not a good idea. Sometimes though, you just cannot avoid it. E.g. when using external libraries and such.

Answer (score 2):

The need points to a faulty design.

But if you really insist writing bad code, you can just cast back to `B *`.

Comment: Yeah, actually my code doesn't have a situation like this. But was just wondering, if I have to do something like this.... But how come it makes a faulty design, so you mean, all the derived class members need to be initialized/modified only through constructors???? or through virtual functions???

Comment: @howtechstuffworks accessing a derived class member from a parent means something is wrong. Parent is a viable object on its own, and should be able to exist without any derived objects, unless its a pure virtual class. The correct way of doing it would be through virtual functions defined at the parent class level.

Comment: ^ Yeah thats how it works now, its an abstract class with pure virtual function....... But I wonder whats the difference between these two? We are going to change it anyway through virtual fucntions, why not use the same thing to datamember and change it directly..... my members are private, I am talking about an friend class....

Comment: @howtechstuffworks I believe that dynamic dispatch is only available for functions (because, amongst other reasons, there's only a single instance of the function per all the instances of the class in memory).

Comment: ^ @littleadv: Yeah I understand there are certain way of doing things, thats why we follow OOP, but I am trying to find a concrete answer for these situation.... Pardon me, if I was silly...\

Answer (score 2):

Without virtual functions the only thing you could do is downcast it.  There's a few ways to go about that:

- You can use dynamic_cast if you have RTTI enabled AND you have at least one virtual function in the parent class, which will let you check to see if the cast succeeded or not.
- static_cast will let you cast to something below you in your inheritance tree, but you lose the ability to check if it succeeded.
- You could also throw caution to the wind completely and use a C-style cast.

Comment: without virtual functions, dynamic_cast isn't available.

Comment: ^ Makes sense...... I was wondering,if we have something like virtual variables or something, which would make lives easier........ But dynamic cast is handy..... Thanks

Comment: ^ yeah..... I use virtual destructor.... Good catch.... Once again....  I didnt run into this kinda situation(yet), just let my imagination bird fly... I am sorry, if I am silly....

Comment: You should tag using @ when replying to someone. I didn't know you edited the answer. By pure luck I came back to this thread to change the vote.